# Add a custom text field to categories in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, seo

I want to add a new text area to my categories in Magento2, similar to this, but its for Magento 1: [adding custom drop down field to category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57915/adding-custom-drop-down-field-to-category)

Basically there should be a field for each category where my customer can put in some category-based SEO content. I want to echo it later on the sidebar.

How could I achieve this? Bonus points if I can achieve this with pure XML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a module that has `Setup/InstallData.php` with content similar to

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);
        $categorySetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'bottom_description');
        $categorySetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'bottom_description', [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Bottom description',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 101,
                'visible' => true,
                'wysiwyg_enabled' => 1,
                'visible_on_front' => 1,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 1,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]
        );
        $idg = $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'General Information');
        $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
            $entityTypeId,
            $attributeSetId,
            $idg,
            'bottom_description',
            46
        );

        //$installer->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'bottom_description', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', 1);
        //$installer->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, 'bottom_description', 'is_html_allowed_on_front', 1);

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
```

Read more [here](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-add-custom-eav-attribute-to-category-or-customer).

Comment: you also need to add the field in the form using the ui component.

Comment: @Vasilii - from the comments of your link it says that this code does not work after Mage 2.0.2. We are currently at 2.0.4 and 2.0.7.

Comment: @Marius: could you please elaborate?

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml#L89) how the fields are added in the category add/edit form. You need to create a file called `view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml` inside your module where you add your new field using the similar markup as in the file I just linked.

Comment: Do I need the common plugin files in my module folder, like registration.php and stuff?

Comment: @Atr_Max function that I wrote here I used on module I've created to add bottom description to category. I've installed it both on 2.0.5 and 2.0.6. No erros and it works perfect :)
You can see my module structure right [here](http://prntscr.com/bdgxxc)

Comment: @Marius not a must.

Comment: Thanks Vasilii. Last question, since I'm not a Mage2 pro (yet) - what needs to be in the view Folder? Can you show me an example, please? I know that there are the files for frontend (or backend), but how do I tell the theme to place the content? :/ Sorry for my stupid questions.

Comment: Tried to use your code, but I don't an extra box when editing or creating a new category. Any things that I could have done wrong here? :/

Comment: @Max the tut on the link support mag2.1 and other for 2.07 and lower with code example in github

Comment: @max in simple ways use this tool https://mage2gen.com to create category or customer attributes and learn how to do with generated code. It will be useful for both leaning and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Create the module in app/code/Max/CategorySeo folder and create below files in your custom module:**

1. Setup/Patch/Data/AddSeoDescriptionCategoryAttribute.php

   ```
    <?php

    declare(strict_types=1);

    namespace Max\CategorySeo\Setup\Patch\Data;

    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
    use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchRevertableInterface;

    class AddSeoDescriptionCategoryAttribute implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface {

    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'seo_description',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'SEO Description',
                'input' => 'text',
                'sort_order' => 333,
                'source' => '',
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => null,
                'group' => 'General Information',
                'backend' => ''
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    public function revert()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'seo_description');

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }
   ```

   }
2. view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="seo_description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">333</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SEO Description</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
   </form>
   ```
3. registration.php

   ```
   <?php

   use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

   ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Max_CategorySeo', __DIR__);
   ```
4. etc/module.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Max_CategorySeo">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
   </config>
   ```